# Java object not populated from json request for inner class

Tags: java, json

Have searched in different sites but couldn't find correct answer, hence posting this request though it could possible duplicates.sorry for that.

I am sending the below json request to my back-end service and converting to java object for processing. I can see the request body passed to my service but when i convert from json to java object , values are not populating

```
{  
  "data":{  
  "username":"martin",
  "customerId":1234567890,
  "firstName":"john",
  "lastName":"smith",
  "password":"p@ssrr0rd@#12",
  "email":"john.smith@gmail.com",
  "contactNumber":"0342323443",
  "department":"sports",
  "location":"texas",
  "status":"unlocked",
  "OrderConfigs":[  
        {  
           "vpnId":"N4234554R",
           "serviceId":"connectNow",
           "serviceType":"WRLIP",
           "ipAddress":"10.101.10.3",
           "fRoute":[  
             "10.255.253.0/30",
             " 10.255.254.0/30"
            ],
         "timeout":1800,
         "mapId":"test_map"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

My Parser class have something like,

```
      JSONObject requestJSON = new JSONObject(requestBody).getJSONObject("data");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final String jsonData = requestJSON.toString();
        OrderDTO mappedObject= mapper.readValue(jsonData , OrderDTO .class);
    // I can see value coming from front-end but not populating in the mappedObject
```

My OrderDTO.java

```
  @JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true,value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "created"})
 public class OrderDTO {

 private String username;
 private long customerId;
 private String source;    
 private String firstName; 
 private String lastName;    
 private String email;  
 private String contactNumber;
 private String password;    
 private String department;    
 private String location;    
 private String status;
 private List<OrderConfig> OrderConfigs;

 @JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
  public class OrderConfig {

    private String vpnId;
    private String serviceId;
    private String serviceType;
    private String ipAddress;      
    private String mapId;         
    private String[] fRoutes;
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;
    private SubConfig subConfig;
    private String routeFlag;

   getter/setters
    .....
   }
  all setter/getter
 }
```

Not sure what I'm missing here. Is this right way to do?

Comment: You don't need `JSONObject` when you are working with Jackson.

Comment: Which fields are not getting populated, all or some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are trying to use inner class, correct way to use is to declare it static for Jackson to work with inner classes.
For reference check [this](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html)

code changes made are

`@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
static class OrderConfig {`

Make sure that your json tag names match with variable names of java object

Ex : "fRoute":[
             "10.255.253.0/30",
             " 10.255.254.0/30"
            ],

private String[] fRoutes;

Answer (score 0):

`OrderConfigs` fields will not be initialized, just modify your bean as

```
@JsonProperty("OrderConfigs")
private List<OrderConfig> orderConfigs;

// setter and getter as setOrderConfigs / getOrderConfigs
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50562217/3295987). (same issue)